How to use conditional app.use() in nestJS backend?
This is how I'm trying to add helmet to my nestJS application. Additionally I need to add graphqlUploadExpress
How do I correctly use the usesUpload condition to use helm or helm + upload?
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js'
import helmet from 'helmet'

const upload = graphqlUploadExpress()

export const main = async (
  AppModule: unknown,
  usesUpload = false
) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, options)
  app.use(usesUpload ? helm : helm, upload) // <-- I think, this is not correct
  await app.listen(3000)
}


I think your ternary statement is wrong. Syntax is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator
This is what I would personally write:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js'
import helmet from 'helmet'

const upload = graphqlUploadExpress()

export const main = async (
  AppModule: unknown,
  usesUpload = false
) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, options)
  usesUpload && app.use(helm, upload)
  await app.listen(3000)
}

Instead of a ternary I am using the Logical AND operator && which then will conditionally execute if the usesUpload argument is true
Logical AND docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND
------ EDIT ------
After I reviewed your question some more, I realized that you want something different, you want to use helm and upload OR just upload I am leaving the above since its still useful, but the following is what you want for your logical statement:
usesUpload ? app.use(helm, upload) : app.use(upload)

